# Connect workbooks and order columns EXCEL

Tags: excel

I've got this workbook, call it master.

Then I have 3 more workbooks connected or linked to the master.

Master has these columns: `A B C D E F`

On workbook 1 I need: `A C D F` -This is OK I can achieve it just deleting the columns I don't want after connection. Then when updating it updates just the columns I have left.

On workbook 2 I need: `A E D C F` -I don't know how to do this.

The idea is that if I make changes to the master, then just clicking on update on the other workbooks they update properly.

Any help please?

Comment: Have you looked at a VBA option

Comment: Not yet. I was looking for some easier solution if avaliable.

Comment: I solved it. You just must grab the coulmn by the bottom of the header cell, not the one whit the letter A B C D E... the one with the name of the column you ar using.